# Why is no gradient available when using sparse tensors in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Computing the gradient of a loss with respect to a variable when the computation involves a sparse tensor returns `None`.

Here's a minimal example:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1,2])

w = tf.get_variable("w", [2, 3])

y = tf.matmul(x, w)

sparse_loss = tf.SparseTensor([[0], [2], [4]], tf.reshape(y, [-1]), [5])

dense_loss = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(sparse_loss)

sparse_grads = tf.gradients(sparse_loss.values, w)
print(sparse_grads)

dense_grads = tf.gradients(dense_loss, w)
print(dense_grads)
```

This prints

```
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1:0' shape=(2, 3) dtype=float32>]
[None]
```

Showing that the gradient is available for the sparse tensor values but not after it has been converted back into a dense tensor.

This is occurring with TensorFlow 1.2 on Ubuntu Linux without a GPU.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the `sparse_to_dense` operation (around which `sparse_tensor_to_dense` is a convenience wrapper) does not have a gradient in TensorFlow 1.2 but this may be solved in TensorFlow 1.3 (see [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6391)). As of today, May 2018, the bug is not fixed yet and has been closed, see [this bug description](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/14552).

A workaround is to have two separate paths through the graph, one that avoids the `sparse_to_dense` operation for the backward pass and one that uses `sparse_to_dense` but for the forward pass only.

An hacky way to get a dense differentiable tensor from a sparse one [is described in here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6391):

```
    dense_tensor_hack = tf.sparse_add(tf.zeros(sparse_tensor.dense_shape), sparse_tensor)
```

Now `dense_tensor_hack` has a well defined gradient.

Comment: Any idea if this has been resolved in subsequent versions?

Comment: @JoshuaR. the linked Github issue includes a comment on 16th Jun 2017 saying "BTW this op now has a gradient." It may also be possible to use `scatter_nd` as an alternative to `sparse_to_dense`.